# Cant access my XAMPP via my public IP address from my local network

Tags: apache, xampp

I did set up a XAMPP installation on my home server. To do that i opened :80 port on my router then forwarded all that traffic into my server local IP (192.168.0.60) then configured XAMPP to listen on 192.168.0.60:80

This is working properly and **I can access my public ip (not 192.168.0.60) and reach my website from outside my local network**.

Here comes the problem:

- **If I access my website from my local network, using my public IP, i get redirected to my router's configuration page**.
- **If I access my website from my local network, using my local IP address (192.168.0.60) then I can see my website but all my CSS scripts are broken because they point to my public IP address, and they cannot be loaded from my network.**
- **If I access my website outside my local network using the server public IP address, it works as intended.**

I cannot display my website properly via http://192.168.0.60/ because my CSS paths are set up with public IP address and not local, so my styles are broken and I cannot work properly on my task.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://PUBLIC.IP/css/style.default.css" id="theme-stylesheet">
```

And my PUBLIC IP redirects me to router, so i cant never see correct css files path from both inside and outside network at the same time, this is forcing me to choose one of them.

Anyone has any hint on this?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)

Since you are redirecting to your server, you will need to use relative paths.

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.default.css" id="theme-stylesheet"/>
```